# How to insert table and bookmark into Word, one per page

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that starts with one table on page one, and then depending on the data in an Excel file, I want to start inserting tables in subsequent pages, and just before each table, I want to insert a text blurb or caption. I'm using a bookmark to insert this text. After inserting the table, I want to add a page break, so that I can start the next table insertion on the next page.

The result I get from the code below places the tables and bookmarks in incorrect order, on seemingly random pages, and in seemingly random order, and the tables are not dimensioned properly (not 6X5 as they should be, but somehow they're 3x3). How can I control the tables, bookmarks, and page breaks to order the document properly?

```
'FROM EXCEL
Dim wd as New Word.Document
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim Rng as Range
Dim d as Variant
dim datMin, datMax as Date
datMin = "04/01/2020"
datMax = "04/05/2020"

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("myFile")
Set Rng = doc.Range(0, 0)
For d = datMin To datMax
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=(d - datMin + 2)) 'Go to top of page
    doc.Bookmarks.Add "D" & d - datMin + 2, Rng  'BOOKMARK NAMES ARE "D2", "D3", etc.
    Rng.Bookmarks("D" & d - datMin + 2).Range.Text = d   'Place Text in bookmark
    doc.Tables.Add Rng, 6, 5  'Add table
    Rng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak  'Add pagebreak
Next d
```

Comment: Modifiying a question, after it has received an answer that addresses the "original question*, is not allowed. If you didn't provide enough information for what you really wanted to ask, ***ask a new question***. Don't invalidate the answer to the original question or expect the person who put in that effort to do so again. If the original question was answered, mark the answer as such to acknowledge the work and effort of the contributor, then ask a new question.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit that changed the question so that the answer matches the question. Please post a new question.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and apologies if any confusion. I asked a new question, separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235793/how-to-insert-tabe-bookmarks-and-pages-into-middle-of-word-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unqualified use of 'Dim Rng as Range' implies to the code that you're referring to an Excel range. Try:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Document, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range, wdTbl As Word.Table
Dim d As Long, StrBkMk As String, datMin As Date, datMax As Date
datMin = "04/01/2020": datMax = "04/05/2020"

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("myFile")
With wdDoc
  For d = datMin To datMax
    StrBkMk = "D" & d
    Set wdRng = .Characters.Last
    With wdRng
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .Text = CDate(d) 'Place Text in bookmark
      .Bookmarks.Add StrBkMk, .Duplicate
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .InsertBefore vbCr
      Set wdTbl = .Tables.Add(.Duplicate, 6, 5)  'Add table
      wdTbl.Range.Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore Chr(12) 'Add pagebreak
    End With
  Next d
  .Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
End With
```

Comment: Many thanks! That works very well to put the new bookmark/table/page breaks at the end of the document. I should've been clearer about what I'm attempting. The orig document is 2 pages, with a table taking up the 1st page, and another table towards the top of the 2nd pg. I'm trying to insert the new tables/bookmarks/pagebreaks in between those 2 tables, at the top of each newly inserted page. I attempted to modify your code to accommodate this, but while close, it's still not there yet. (pls see my edit to OP). It puts the 1st tbl etc. in right place, but not subsequent ones. Any ideas? Tks!

Comment: So what is *between* those two tables?

Comment: Nothing is between those two tables. Just a few blank paragraphs.

Comment: «a few blank paragraphs» isn't nothing. How many? And how many of these blank paragraphs should be retained before and after the new content?